# JSONP parse error, Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, jsonp

Is it possible to wrap a JSON response the way JSONP does? from this response format(which is the type of response I am getting):

```
{"specialOffer":"rollback","format":"json"}
```

to this format

```
jQuery321049913783140015044_1515731209916({"query":"test"})
```

I am getting a parse error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI8Tb.png)

But when I paste the url in the browser or in Chrome Rest Client, I can see the response correctly, so I dont understand how can I access the response.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://api.urlexample.com/',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));

        console.log(response);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, exception) {
        var msg_err = "";
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            msg_err = "Not connect. Verify Network.";
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            msg_err = "Requested page not found. [404]";
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            msg_err = "Internal Server Error [500].";
        } else if (exception === "parsererror") {
            msg_err = "Requested JSON parse failed.";
        } else if (exception === "timeout") {
            msg_err = "Time out error.";
        } else if (exception === "abort") {
            msg_err = "Ajax request aborted.";
        } else {
            msg_err = "Uncaught Error. "+ jqXHR.responseText;
        }
        alert(msg_err);
    })
    .always(function() {
        alert("complete");
    });
    });
```

if I use the parameter `jsonpCallback:myCallback` it accesses the callback function but I get the error:

Callback function

```
window.myCallback = function(data) {

    console.log('Accessed callback');
};
```

Output

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot assign to read only property
>   'undefined' of object '#' TypeError: Cannot assign to read
>   only property 'undefined' of object '#'

Comment: You can't force an api to return JSONP if that api doesn't serve JSONP. Not all do. Use a proxy instead either on server you control or third party service

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to get around CORS issues by converting a JSON response to JSONP on the client - which won't work for a variety of reasons.